# convert Object inside a string to array

Tags: php

I am getting from url value something like below:

```
$param = "{year:2019,month:5,id:3}"
```

I am not being able to convert it to array.

Can anybody please help me

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific issues are you getting?

Comment: I try to remove the string from it. tried json_decodes. but i could not  solve

Comment: This is invalid json as it says in [php doc (Example #3 common mistakes using json_decode())](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Can you ask those who send a request change the message format?

Comment: @marv255 I cannot  request them  That is what I am getting.

Comment: @user1687891 maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836548/handling-malformed-json-in-php) could help you. But I don't recommend to use regexp for json, only if you a 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you have a string like this it is possible that values can cause problems due to containing values you don't expect (like commas or colons).  So to just add to the confusion and because it was just an interesting experiment I came up with the idea of translating the string to a URL encoded string (with & and =) and then parsing it as though it was a parameter string...

```
parse_str(strtr($param, ["{" => "", "}" => "", ":" => "=", "," => "&"]), $params);
```

gives the `$params` array as...

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2019
    [month] => 5
    [id] => 3
)
```

Comment: If a comma in the original data was problematic, then I don’t see how that comma replaced by a `&` would be any less problematic, when you try and parse the result as a query string. `{year:20,19,month:5,id:3}` still results in `'year' => '20'` and `'19' => ''` here.

Comment: I know this can be cause new problems hence the *So to just add to the confusion*

Answer (score 1):

I think that needs to be parsed manually.

First explode on comma without `{}` to separate each of the key value pairs then loop and explode again to separate key from values.

```
$param = explode(",", substr($param, 1, -1));

foreach($param as $v){
    $temp = explode(":", $v);
    $res[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}

var_dump($res);

/*
array(3) {
  ["year"]=>
  string(4) "2019"
  ["month"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}*/
```

https://3v4l.org/naIJE

Answer (score 0):

Your json isn't well formatted. Try this:

```
$param = '{"year":2019,"month":5,"id":3}';
var_dump(json_decode($param, true));
```

Comment: yes if data is like that, then its easy. but in my case what shall I do .

Comment: Then you can try with `explode()` to get what you need and write that array yourself